# ag-grid webpack css not making to the website

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag-grid in my react app, cannot make the css work with webpack.

grid is looking like this

image:
[image]

```
const path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
let CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
var BitBarWebpackProgressPlugin = require("bitbar-webpack-progress-plugin");
let plug = require("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: "css-loader/locals"
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  context: path.join(__dirname, "Scripts", "src"),
  entry: {
    d1: "./entries/d1Page.js",
    h1: "./entries/h1Page.js",
    polyfills: "./entries/polyfills.js",
    d2: "./entries/d2Page.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "Scripts/dist"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/Scripts/dist/"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".json", ".js", ".jsx", ".css"]
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  plugins: [new BitBarWebpackProgressPlugin()],
  mode: "development"
};
```

and importing the CSS in my components like this

```
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
.
.
.
```

part of my packages.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
"@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"bitbar-webpack-progress-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
"css-loader": "^1.0.1",
"es6": "0.0.7",
"es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"html-loader": "^0.5.5",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"webpack": "^4.26.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
"whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.2.0",
"ag-grid-react": "^20.2.0"
```

tried different types of loader, reolserver as suggested in ag-grid still no luck. any idea what is going on in here?

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look closely on file paths and file names.
Check if your current import method is correct.

Try

```
@import url('../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css');
@import url('../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-fresh.css');
```

Add

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css"
],
```

to .angular-cli.json

**Remember to use your path on imports and styles**

Try to change `.css` to `.scss` on imports.

Open up the console (browser) or look at the terminal (depends on project) and search for errors.

Read docs too: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/

Here is a GitHub demo for you: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-angular-example

Hope this helps!

Brhaka

Comment: btw, I am using react but will see look into your suggestions.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your import statements for the Ag-Grid CSS files and the [Ag-Grid documentation for React](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-more-details/#loading-css), it looks like you are missing the configuration of a resolution alias for the `ag-grid-community` directory within `node_modules`.

Add the following to your Webpack configuration:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "ag-grid-community": path.resolve('./node_modules/ag-grid-community')
    }
},
```

Additionally, you may have to revise your CSS loader within the Webpack configuration.  There are several good example Webpack configurations within [ag-grid-react-example](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react-example) on GitHub:

- [webpack.config.examples.js](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react-example/blob/master/config/webpack.config.examples.js)
- [webpack.config.large.js](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react-example/blob/master/config/webpack.config.large.js)
- [webpack.config.trader.js](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-react-example/blob/master/config/webpack.config.trader.js)

According to these example Webpack configurations, the CSS loader is configured as

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },
```

Hope this helps!